# How to validate that value is an Integer with Firebase rules

Tags: validation, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to make sure that some field of an object in firebase is an integer and not decimal. There is a method [isNumber()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#isnumber) but it returns true wheter value is an integer or a decimal.

I've tried to check a value with regex, but for some reason it works properly only with values within quotation marks ie strings.

This is how my rule looks:

```
"$item_id":{
    "created":{
    ".validate":"newData.val().matches(/^[0-9]+$/)"
    }
}
```

So when I put an object with string value like this `{"created":"123456789"}` validation works fine. But when I put an object with number value `{"created":123456789}` validation fails.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use a regular expression to validate a number, since regular expressions match patterns in strings.

You can also not really validate that something is an integer, since JavaScript doesn't have a separate integer vs floating point type. They're all just floating point numbers.

What you *can* validate is that something is a whole number. The simplest way I could come up with is:

```
".validate":"newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1 === 0.0"
```

This accepts `1` and `1.0`, but will reject `1.1`.

Comment: Perfect! This can be combined with type checking from the app side to ensure it will be an Int 100%.